# iOS Checkboxes using bootstrap won't center

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am struggling to get checkboxes to center correctly on iOS due to WebKit styling them. I am using bootstrap to create the responsive design.

This is the results of my code that is being ruined by iOS:

[image: iOS styling of bootstrap checkbox]

I am using the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-5 col-sm-2" for="formatA">Format:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="formatA" name="formatA">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="formatD" name="formatD" placeholder="Enter date of format approval">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if the vertical centering problem is iOS exclusive, try -webkit-appearance: none on the checkboxes.

Comment: It's horizontal centering that is the issue, sorry I should have been clearer, I will update my question. I have tried your solution and it just makes the checkboxes behave very strangely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I've made a plunker with the solution. I looked at the bootstrap grid syntax again an kinda saw that there might be some issues with how you laid out your grid. I started from the beginning again and this is what I came up with

http://plnkr.co/edit/x3vDfl15LA2yxxDOeUQT

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label class="control-label" for="formatA">Format:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="checkbox" class="" id="formatA" name="formatA" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="formatD" name="formatD" placeholder="Enter date of format approval" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
html{
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]{
      display:block;
      margin:0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    input[type="date"]{
      width:100%;
    }
```

That got me this result on my iPhone 6+
[iphone6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlKUh.png)

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to have no effect, they still stay aligned to the left

Comment: Oh, try adding a width to the checkboxes, like 50 px or something I'll change my answer to reflect

Comment: Still no effect, just pushes the page to be wider, but has no effect on the checkbox itself. This is because of the apples strict webkit styling.

Comment: k I'll do some more research.

Comment: Thank you, I have been struggling with it for a few days on and off, I keep giving up and thinking it can stay like that but the perfectionist in me won't allow it haha.

Comment: Ok i have a solution that hundo p centres the box. updating the answer now